# Nested Optidef Equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

How might we specify a bilevel optimization problem using optidef? I would like to specify one ([see](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/104085/1/MPRA_paper_104085.pdf) equations 6 and 7 at the bottom and top of pages 4 and 5 respectively). So far, I do it like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,optidef,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{mini}
{L,V}{L_V\left(V,W \right) ||\mathbf{X}_{1}-\mathbf{X}_{0} ||^{2}_{\mathbf{V}} \quad \forall \: t \in T_0 \label{eq:scbi}}{}{}
\addConstraint {W\left(V \right) \in \Psi \left(V \right) \coloneqq \underset{W \in \mathcal{W}}{\text{argmin }} L_W\left(V,W \right) ||\mathbf{X}_{1}-\mathbf{X}_{0}W ||^{2}_{\mathbf{V}}, V \in \mathcal{V}}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

I define the second optimization problem manually using underset, but I was curious if there's a way to define a lower level problem and an upper level problem, perhaps using two instances of optidef. How might I do this?

Comment: I have not understood the question. Please can you simplify your question or put a drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the useless `\left` and `\right`; also `||` should be `\|` or, even better `\lVert` for opening and `\rVert` for closing.

It's not easy to understand why `optidef` seems to ignore the width, but adding `\mbox{}` in the last part happens to work.

Define a suitable math operator for “argmin”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{optidef}
\usepackage{showframe}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini}[constraintFormat=3]
{L,V}{
  L_V(V,W) \|\mathbf{X}_{1}-\mathbf{X}_{0} \|^{2}_{\mathbf{V}} \quad \forall \: t \in T_0 
  \label{eq:scbi}
}{}{}
\addConstraint{W(V) \in \Psi(V)}{\coloneqq 
  \argmin_{W \in \mathcal{W}} L_W(V,W) \|\mathbf{X}_{1}-\mathbf{X}_{0}W \|^{2}_{\mathbf{V}},
  V \in \mathcal{V}}{\mbox{}}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The heavy rules show the margins, courtesy of `showframe`. Remove the call to the package in the production version.